# Rails: Group By join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, group-by

I am trying to group by a delegate join table.  I have a tasks table and each task is has a project_id.  The following code works well in my controller for me to group by project:

```
@task = Task.joins(:project).joins(:urgency).where(urgencies: {urgency_value: 7}).group_by(&:project_id)
```

This returns a hash where the key is what I have joined by and then the index contains each tasks within that group.  I can then loop through each task to retrieve its attributes.

However, each project belongs to a workspace (via a workspace_id).  What I want is to have the same query but to group by the workspace.  The final aim is for me to create a table which shows the workspace name in one column and the number of tasks for that workspace in the second column.

I have tried many combinations and searched many forums but after several hours still haven't been able to crack it.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what are the relations among the four tables you mention (tasks, projects, urgencies, workspaces). I think a Task belongs_to a Project, but beyond that I would have to guess. Please clarify what belongs_to what, and what has_many of what.

Comment: Sorry, the relationships are: Task belongs_to Project and Urgency, Project belongs_to Workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your only goal is to get the task counts per workspace, I think you want a different query.

```
@workspaces_with_task_counts = 
  Workspace
    .joins(:projects)
    .joins(:tasks)
    .select('workspaces.name, count(tasks.id) as task_count')
    .group(:workspace_id)
```

Then you can access the count like this:

```
@workspaces_with_task_counts.each do |workspace|
  puts "#{workspace.name}: #{workspace.task_count}"
end
```

**EDIT 1**

I think this is what you want:

```
Workspace
  .joins(projects: { tasks: :urgencies })
  .where(urgencies: {urgency_value: 7})
  .group(:name)
  .count
```

which results in a hash containing all of the workspaces with at least one task where the urgency_value is 7, by name, with the number of tasks in that workspace:

```
{"workspace1"=>4, "workspace2"=>1}
```

**EDIT 2**

SQL is not capable of returning both detail and summary information in a single query. But, we can get all the data, then summarize it in memory with Ruby's `group_by` method:

```
Task
  .joins(project: :workspace)
  .includes(project: :workspace)
  .group_by { |task| task.project.workspace.name }
```

This produces the following data structure:

```
{
  "workspace1": [task, task, task],
  "workspace2": [task, task],
  "workspace3": [task, task, task, task]
}
```

But, it does so at a cost. Grouping in memory is an expensive process. Running that query 10,000 times took ~15 seconds.

It turns out that executing two SQL queries is actually two orders of magnitude faster at ~0.2 seconds. Here are the queries:

```
tasks = Task.joins(project: :workspace).includes(project: :workspace)
counts = tasks.group('workspaces.name').count
```

The first query gets you all the tasks and preloads their associated project and workspace data. The second query uses ActiveRecord's `group` clause to construct the SQL statement to summarize the data. It returns this data structure:

```
{ "workspace1": 3, "workspace2": 2, "workspace3": 4 }
```

Databases are super efficient at set manipulation. It's almost always significantly faster to do that work in the database than in Ruby.

Comment: I also want to display all of the tasks within each individual workspace.

Comment: @DRadnor - updated answer. Ignore the bit above the EDIT.

Comment: this is great but how do I access all of the attributes of the tasks within each workspace?  I need to be able to see at a high level how many high urgency tasks there are within each workspace and then see what those tasks are.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @DRadnor - updated again. Hope that meets your needs.

Comment: So it looks like I need to use the less efficient Ruby's group_by method as I need to display all of the tasks per workspace.  Or could I use the 2 SQL queries and then within the View loop through the results from the query that returns all of the tasks.  Would this be equally inefficient?